# Why is the integral of $\frac{1}{3x}$ not $\frac{ln(3x)}{3}$?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus

Why is the integral of $\frac{1}{3x}$ not $\frac{ln(3x)}{3}$ ?

Using the formula that the integral of $\frac{1}{ax+b}$ is $\frac{ln(ax+b)}{a}$?

P.S. I know it should be $\frac{lnx}{3}$ but why is the previous working wrong? I am confused.

(+C)

Comment: This needs to have a canonical answer. As usually it will be that $\ln(3x)=\ln x+\ln 3$ and $\ln 3$ is *absorbed* into the constant. So the integral of $\frac{1}{3x}$ is $\frac{\ln(3x)}{3}+C$, but also $\frac{\ln x}{3} +K$. $C\neq K$.

Comment: Who says your answer is wrong?

Comment: Do you find yourself forgetting the plus C a lot?  [See this comic](http://spikedmath.com/434.html).  Also, if you get tired of adding C and would like other alternatives, [see this comic](http://spikedmath.com/508.html).

Comment: Thanks, This is very explanatory

Comment: @JMoravitz Too bad that stamp is going to print Ɔ+.

Comment: @kccu you're holding it upside down

Comment: @JMoravitz: One of my teachers was fond of adding "stick figure".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{\ln|3x|}{3}$ is *an* antiderivative of $\frac{1}{3x}$. But notice by properties of logarithms that
$$\frac{\ln|3x|}{3} = \frac{\ln(3|x|)}{3} = \frac{\ln 3 + \ln|x|}{3} = \frac{\ln|x|}{3} + \frac{\ln 3}{3}.$$

Also recall that you can add or subtract a constant from any antiderivative to obtain another antiderivative. So in particular, another antiderivative for $\frac{\ln|3x|}{3}$ is
$$\frac{\ln|x|}{3}+\frac{\ln 3}{3} - \frac{\ln 3}{3} = \frac{\ln|x|}{3}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Why do you say the integral of $\frac{1}{3x}$ not $\frac{\ln(3x)}{3}$ ? ... it is.

You say that the integral is $\frac{\ln x}{3}$, which is also right.  These two integrals differ by a constant, of course.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\ln(3x)}3=\frac{\ln x+\ln 3}3=\frac{\ln x}3+\frac{\ln 3}3$$
This function and
$$\frac{\ln x}3$$
have the same derivative.